# Перезапись значения ячейки БД в sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть два запроса но как подружить не знаю), нужно выбрать конкретную ячейку и перезаписать.

```
SELECT number_question FROM USERS WHERE  id IS 648226895
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO   (number_question) VALUES (3)
```

Если подробнее, то есть два столбца в таблице USERS, id и number_question, так вот нужно найти в столбце id 648226895 и в этой же строке перезаписать значение ячейки столбца number_question.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE USERS SET number_question=3 WHERE id IS 648226895`

Comment: Здравствуйте! Постарайтесь, пожалуйста, оставлять более развёрнутые ответы для лучшего понимания вашего решения, вопрос можно отредактировать нажав кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1438492/edit).